# how to install worklight developer edition in eclipse Juno on windows 7?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I want to develop mobile applications. For that I need IBM Worklight studio. 
I have been trying to install **worklight studio** in **eclipse Juno** on my **Windows7** system. But I couldn't install and I have no idea how to install it even.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: 'I tried to install' + 'I could not install' is not very useful info. Please edit your question. **What** file(s) did you try to install, **what step** failed, **What error message** did you get?

Answer (score 4):

Perform these steps:

- Install Eclipse Juno SR2 (**IMPORTANT**: SR2 is the only version
  currently supported)
- Run Eclipse as Administrator
- Install the Worklight plugin to [your plugin repository](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/install_plugin/index_v35.html)

  - DEVELOPER EDITION: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/worklight/
  - ENTERPRISE EDITION: Download from IBM Software Access Catalog
- Done! You are able to create a new Worklight project

If this is not clear please refer to the Information Center: 
[Installing Worklight Studio](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devenv/t_installing_ibm_worklight_studi.html)